# Is there a definitive list of W3C-standardised technologies?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, w3c

There are many languages (PHP, nodeJS etc.) and libraries (jQuery, Ruby on Rails etc.) used in the building of websites and web-apps.

But is there a definitive list of W3C-standardised technologies?

If I were asked to name W3C-standardised web technologies, I would list:

- HTML5
- CSS3
- Javascript
- SVG
- JSON
- XML

Are there any other W3C-standardised technologies(as opposed to third-party languages and libraries) ?

Comment: How do you know above is WTC-endorsed? I didn't know W3C endorsed any technologies, don't they just write specifications for protocols etc? BTW why have versions at HTML and CSS and not on others?

Comment: I am happy to use another adjective in place of _endorsed_. What adjective would you recommend?

Comment: AFAIK W3C only sets standards and recommendations for Big companies to follow, more like a common goal so they don't implement things differently.  Maybe a right construction would be technologies revised or standardized by W3C. Altho, after recent EME fiasco, I hope they dissolve cause they are clearly being lobbied over by capital.

Comment: @DanteTheSmith The C in W3C stands for Consortium. The W3C is the place where companies, etc (big and not so big) decided it was the place to discuss matters related to the Web and that it was better for them to be part of it, discuss and cooperate on standards rather than compete. W3C doesn't dictate anything; they offer a place where negociations take place. The Web is better _with_ the W3C than _without_ IMHO. And without DRM but that's another matter...

Comment: By no means is W3C the only place where standards are created. Both JavaScript and JSON are standardized elsewhere.

Comment: @FelipeAls I agree with both your statements. Still, I think they should also influence their recommendation, they are all experts and should prevent lobbies from forcing harmful ideas. Neutrality of web is one of its core principles the very essence of it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many more things the W3 is involved in. See [W3: All Standards and Drafts](https://www.w3.org/TR/) or (probably incomplete) [Wikipedia: W3 Standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium#Standards).

Comment: What do you consider "core"? There are many things in these lists that are essential to today's web.

Comment: All these standards and drafts from the World Wide **Web** Consortium are web technologies. "Core" or not is opinion-based and thus not suited for a question on SO